# Number of substrings that doesn't contain given strings (Large constraint)

Tags: string, substring, trie, suffix-array

I recently discovers an interesting problem on the web. A brief statement in the following:

Note that the overall time limit should not exist 1.00s (Time complexity < 10^8)

Now student A found a string that only consist of lowercases character. He want to cut a substring to student B as a present. Student B has a list of strings that he think it is "ugly". Can u help student A to find the number of ways to cut a substring that doesn't contain any "ugly" strings. (Mind that same substring but from different position also count).

```
Example:
Student A: abcdabcdab
Ugly strings: cd, da

Output: 17

Explanation:
    The 17 cuttings are "a" (appears 3 times), "ab" (appears 3 times), 
    "abc" (appears 2 times), "bc" (appears 2 times), "b" (appears 3 times),
    "c" (appears 2 times) and "d" (appears 2 times)
```

I first thought it is an easy problem but that constraint is quite large. The maximum length of student A's string is 100000 while there may be at most 500000 ugly strings with maximum length of 500000.

I try to solve to solve this problem using suffix trie but failed miserably because of the memory limit. Can anyone suggest a possible way to solve the problem. It is some kinda advanced data structures related problem e.g. suffix array

A code in any programming language is recommended with proper description is preferred. Because I find it better if there is an actually code to do study.

Answer (score 0):

Since equal substrings starting at different positions count as different substrings, the maximum number of substrings of a string with length n is n*(n + 1) / 2. (n substrings that start at position 0, n-1 substrings that start at position 1, and so on).

If an ugly string is contained in a substring of length q starting at position p, all substrings starting at p with a length > q will also contain that ugly string.

If an ugly string is longer than the substring itself, it won't match.

My first attempt would look like this:

```
String ugly[]; // is provided somehow; at most 500000 with max length of 500000
String student; // the String to cut into substrings, max length 100000
long num = 0;

ugly.sort(); // by length

for (int start = 0; start < student.size() - 1, ++start) {
    for (int end = start + 1; end < student.size(); ++end) {
        String s = student.substr(start, end);
        int lgth = s.size();
        int u = 0;
        while (lgth >= ugly[u].size()) {
            if (s.contains(ugly[u])) break;
            ++u;
        }
        if (lgth < ugly[u].size()) {
            ++num; // we checked all potentially matching uglies
        } else {
            break; // leave the inner loop and 
                   // start with the next position
        }
    }
}
```

---

My second attempt would take another approach. I'd start to develop this one if this task has to be performed more than only a few times.

If I have a string `student` and an ugly string of length p that matches somewhere, the string `student` can be cut into two parts: the first part that ends with the first p-1 characters of the ugly string and the second part that starts with the last p-1 characters of the ugly string.

This can be repeated until the ugly string doesn't match anywhere. We then have a number of substrings and an ugly string that doesn't match any of them. Hence this ugly string can be discarded.

Repeating this for all ugly strings, you'll get a list of "longest" substrings that don't match any of the ugly strings.
Now you can iterate over this list and add length * (length + 1)/2 to the final result.

So it would look like

```
String ugly[]; // as before
String student; // as before
long num = 0;
Vector substrs = new Vector();

ugly.sort(); // by length
substrs.add(student);

void splitStr(String str2split, String pattern, Vector result)
{
    if (str2split.size() < pattern.size()) {
        result.add(str2split);
        return;
    } else {
        int pos = str2split.contains(pattern); // returns position, -1 if not found
        if (pos >= 0) { // found
            String s1 = str2split.substr(0, pos + pattern.size() - 1);
            String s2 = str2split.substr(pos + 1, str2split.size());
            // add s1 and repeat split on s2
            result.add(s1);
            splitStr(s2, pattern, result);
        } else {
            // not found, entire string is ok
            result.add(str2split);
        }
    }
}

for (int u = 0; u < ugly.size(); ++u) {
    Vector newSubstrs = new Vector();
    String ugly2test = ugly[u];
    for (int i = 0; i < substrs.size(); ++i) {
        String t = substrs.get(i);
        splitStr(t, ugly2test, newSubstrs);
    }
    substrs = newSubstrs;
}

for (int i = 0; i < substrs.size(); ++i) {
    String s = substrs.get(i);
    num += s.size() * (s.size() + 1) / 2;
}
```

Note: this is basically the idea. I didn't test any code (which is java like, but probably won't compile), I only translated my plain text idea in some sort of pseudocode.

Comment: Ur code time complexity in the worst case is O(500000*500000*100000) I think it will exceed the time limit

Comment: Well, with n equal the length of the string to split into substrings and m equal the number of ugly patterns, the number of operations is O(n² m). (m * n * (n + 1) / 2). (I didn't account for the search, which adds another n; hence O(n^4)). But finding ugly patterns speeds things up significantly.
There are things you can do to reduce the number of ugly patterns (e.g. longer patterns that contain a shorter pattern can be eliminated), but I can just as well assume that the set of ugly patterns can't be reduced.

Comment: You can take advantage of single character ugly patterns. You can cut all of them out of your original string, yielding a set of substrings. Each of those can be processed with my algorithm. Because of the reduced length, it'll be much faster.

Comment: I think just the part for exhausting the possible substring will already cause Time limit exceed. (O(N^2))

Comment: Well, somehow you'll have to count them. Clearly, if you have a substring of student of length p that doesn't match any of the ugly patterns, you can add `p(p+1)/2` to the result. So maybe going backward (start with the entire substring that starts at some position and make it shorter if you have a hit (use the position of the hit)) will speed things up.

Comment: On the other hand, my algorithm doesn't do it that bad. As soon as an ugly pattern matches, it'll continue with the next position. Up till then, only the "short" ugly patterns are tested. The contains() test can be replaced with an endsWith(), taking advantage of the fact that the last iteration didn't find something. That reduces the search overhead significantly.

Comment: I don't know if you noticed I added a second approach in my answer. The complexity is still quadratic or worse, but that can't be avoided. You'll always have to check at least all m ugly patterns to be present within your n character string at least once. No way to avoid O(nm).